# How do I monitor a different folder (than the default) within Outlook for new mail (and then fire an event) with Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I have the below code

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import time

    class Handler_Class(object):
    
        def OnNewMailEx(self, receivedItemsIDs):
            for ID in receivedItemsIDs.split(","):
                mailItem = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(ID)
                print(mailItem.Subject)
                
    outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class)        
   
    print("[" + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y") + "] " + " Running...")
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

The above python code monitors my default Outlook inbox (when Outlook is open) and fires an event when a new mail comes in. This code works fine for the default Outbox inbox, but I'd like to rather monitor a shared inbox rather than the default one. The shared email address is 'blah@my.company.com' and then i want to look inside 'inbox' folder.

I tried the below code to try get it to monitor for new mail on the shared inbox in Outlook but it seems not to be working...

**Does anyone have any ideas?**

```
outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class).GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders['blah@my.company.com'].Folders['Inbox']
```

Comment: Once you have your folder, try handling the Items.ItemAdd event. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the default inbox folder for the shared mailbox. Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Inbox` folder). The following VBA sample shows how to use this method:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

After you have got the folder reference you can set up the `ItemAdd` event on the `Items` collection of that folder. The [Items.ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) event is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Note, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than sixteen).

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way. I know is not elegant nor professional but it works:

```
outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Outlook.Application", Handler_Class).GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders['blah@my.company.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['the folder name you need to monitor']
```

If you need the items in this you can add at the end `.Items` but I think you already know that :)